# Legal considerations about pentesting and scanning by country

Tags: penetration-test, legal

We have a pentesting opportunity, and this one is for a company that has multiple data centers around the globe. Now from my research on the [Penetration Testing Execution Standard](http://www.pentest-standard.org/index.php/Pre-engagement#Legal_Considerations) I realize that it's illegal to pentest and do port scans in certain countries.

Is there a resource that can provide me with the legality of pentesting, port scanning and vulnerability scanning by country?

This would go a long way towards helping us pentesters research if certain opportunities are valid or not.

Comment: If you stick to your customer subnets and will have agreement on that and it will be performed during agreed timeframe it will be OK. The problem is when you are scanning networks which you shouldn't, so it's good to agree on the subnets first. If you are scanning shared hosting - this is impossible to do pen-testing, you'd rather use Test platform for that.

Comment: The example given on that page is not specific enough to be helpful. Monitoring VoIP would only be wiretapping if you didn't have the permission from all parties. But then why would you pen test the voice part of a VoIP system? Probably more bother than it is worth except in very specific circumstances. I am not aware of any laws anywhere that would be violated if permission is obtained from all parties (including suppliers). Though that might not hold true in some highly restrictive places such as China. In those cases, checking local laws will be needed anyway as things may change.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This has been helpful. I wasn't sure how to go about checking the legality for this in countries like Nepal, but if we have signed permission then it should be fine. Thank you.